Generate Build version by calculating number of builds today
I am trying to generate a build version number in my workflow as follows:
# Step : Generate Build Version Number
- name: Generate Build Version Number
  id: GET_BUILD_VERSION
  run: |
    # Calculate the number of builds today
    BUILDS_TODAY=$(seq -f v${{ github.run_number }}.%g $((${{ github.run_number }} - 1)))

    # Generate the build version with the number of builds today
    BUILD_VERSION_GENERATED=$(date +v%Y.%m%d.${#BUILDS_TODAY[@]})
    echo "Generated Build Version: $BUILD_VERSION_GENERATED"
    echo "BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION_GENERATED" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "BUILD=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "::set-output name=build_version::$BUILD_VERSION_GENERATED"

But this is generating version number as v2024.0426.1 and the BUILDS_TODAY is remaining same as 1 and is not getting incremented. The value is supposed to increment as v2024.0426.x where x is the number of builds that happen today. Is there anything that is preventing it from incrementing the number?

_"# Step : Generate Build Version Number

name: Generate Build Version Number"_ - don't write comments like this.


Either make the output an array i.e. BUILDS_TODAY=($(seq ...)) or simply append wc -l at the end and get the count directly i.e. BUILDS_TODAY=$(seq ... | wc -l). Without making it an array, it's a single line and that's why the count is 1. Apart from that, you can use the default env var $GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER instead of ${{ github.run_number }} expression.
